# Is there a way to print a double in java without the decimal ".0" after the number, only if there isn't one?

Tags: java

I tried programming something like this:

```
double d = 4.0;
    if(d * 10 % 10 == 0){
        System.out.println((int)d);
    }else{
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

but I would like a more condensed version for competitive programming